# Check X509 certificate revocation status in Spring-Security before authenticating

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, x509

Is it possible to check the revocation status of a x509 client certificate through the CRL in spring-security before authenticating it? I've checked documentations (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/x509.html) but it doesn't mention anything about CRL.

Implementing UserService only gives you the username and not the X509Certificate. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about the specifics of Spring-Security, but if it's based on the trustmanagers of the JRE (if if it's the Oracle/Sun JRE), you can activate CRL checks by setting these system properties to `true`: `com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation` and `com.sun.security.enableCRLDP`, and setting `Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "true")` (thanks to @WillSargent for pointing out it's a `Security` property, not a system one).

More details here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CERTPATH
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AppC
- http://blogs.oracle.com/xuelei/entry/enable_ocsp_checking

Comment: This is not quite accurate: you need to set _Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable")_, not System.setProperty

Comment: @WillSargent. Not sure what you mean. Did I say anything different?

Comment: "setting these system properties" -- ocsp.enable is not a system property.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your comment (and I didn't quite remember that old answer).

Answer (score 5):

The SSL handshake is performed by the servlet container, rather than Spring Security, so any CRL checking should probably occur at that point. Spring Security treats it as a "pre-authentication" scenario.

Spring Security just reads the (already SSL-authenticated) certificate and allows you to link it to a local user account.