# Enable SSL certificate revocation checking in OpenJDK 11

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, java-11, certificate-revocation

Is there some quick "declarative" way in Java 11, instead of a tedious manual implementation, to enable checking if a certificate is revoked?

I tried to use properties from this answer:
[Check X509 certificate revocation status in Spring-Security before authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506661/check-x509-certificate-revocation-status-in-spring-security-before-authenticatin/8507905#8507905)
with this dummy revoked certificate: https://revoked.badssl.com
but the code always accepts the certificate. Am I doing something wrong or these properties are no more actual for Java 11? If so, do we have any alternatives?

Below is my code:

```
public static void validateOnCertificateRevocation(boolean check) {
    if (check) {
        System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableCRLDP", "true");

        Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "true");
    }

    try {
        new URL("https://revoked.badssl.com").openConnection().connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like those options have to be set before the first request has been performed.

Therefore the following code as standalone Java program throws an `CertPathValidatorException: Certificate has been revoked` (tested using OpenJDK 11.0.2 x64 on Windows):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateOnCertificateRevocation(true); // throws CertPathValidatorException
}
```

However the following code does not cause any errors/Exceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateOnCertificateRevocation(false);
    validateOnCertificateRevocation(true); // nothing happens
}
```

You can see the changing the options after the first request has been processed isn't effective. I assume that those options are processed in a `static { ... }` block of some certificate validation related class.

If you still want to enable/disable certificate revocation checking on a per-request base you can do so by implementing your own [`X509TrustManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertPathValidator.html) that uses [`CertPathValidator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertPathValidator.html) (for which you can enable/disable certificate revocation checking via `PKIXParameters.setRevocationEnabled(boolean)`.

Alternatively there is the solution to globally enable certificate revocation checking and explicitly handle the CertificateRevokedException:

```
private boolean checkOnCertificateRevocation;

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    try {
        getDefaultTrustManager().checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        if (checkOnCertificateRevocation) {
            if (getRootCause(e) instanceof CertificateRevokedException) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The "com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation" property is actually, as you supposed, being processed only once in initializing of the static field "checkTLSRevocation" in "sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator" class. So, as a workaround, we could always keep this property enabled and catch/rethrow exception basing on the boolean flag in client code. But maybe there exist some more elegant solution for enabling/disabling the revocation checking in every request?

Comment: You could implement an own `X509TrustManager` that uses `CertPathValidator` to validate the certificate. The used `PKIXParameters` class has a method named `setRevocationEnabled(boolen)` which can enable/disable cert revocation checking. This should work on a per-request level.

Comment: Appreciate your help! However, after several tries to implement overcomplicated `CertPathValidator` it has been decided to stick with "always throw, catch when needed" principle. The final code of custom `X509TrustManager` now looks like
`@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
try {
  getDefaultTrustManager().checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
 } catch (CertificateException e) {
  if (checkOnCertificateRevocation) {
   if (getRootCause(e) instanceof CertificateRevokedException) {
    throw e;
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @Roman I updated my answer and included our discussion from the comments.