# SSL TrustStore without CA, only client certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I have a custom CAroot.crt (generated by me) and all my clients certificates are signed with this CAroot.crt. I have a TrustStore.jks where I put only clients certificates and not CAroot.crt, because I would like to have the possibility to remove a client from my truststore any time.

When I try to start my application I got the following:

```
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
main, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
```

This is my trustStore.jks:

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: localhost
Creation date: Nov 23, 2019
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=localhost, OU=IT, O=QUEROBUY, L=SAO CAETANO DO SUL, ST=SAO PAULO, C=BR
Issuer: CN=localhost, OU=IT, O=LANHELLAS XYZ, L=SAO CAETANO DO SUL, ST=SAO PAULO, C=BR
Serial number: 5416c04e360f9d50323c52d8a5b04be2969c9b86
Valid from: Sat Nov 23 16:39:54 BRT 2019 until: Tue Apr 06 16:39:54 BRT 2021
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  8F:29:1C:1F:05:89:0B:E6:A0:57:84:FE:B0:78:68:2D
     SHA1: 95:C8:EA:0E:C8:7C:4E:99:E4:73:85:49:57:D6:BB:88:AF:52:52:12
     SHA256: 7E:ED:19:AF:02:DB:CC:88:98:D0:10:4E:39:67:AA:4D:3F:70:DA:76:03:1B:CB:41:06:DC:3B:51:38:16:78:5F
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

If I add "CARoot.crt" to my trustStore.jks everything works fine, but I lose the chance to invalidate some specific client certificate. Imagine, I have 10 clients, each one with your own certificate (.crt) assigned by "CARoot.crt" but Client 001 for some reason should be invalidated immediately, I will just remove your public key from trustStore.jks in server, without that I should wait for certificate expiration date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WHY:** if you look slightly earlier in the debuglog you will see the `CertificateRequest` message, which specifies (among other things) the Cert[ificate] Authorities the server asks for; see [rfc5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4). Java defines this as the Subject names of the certs in the truststore, because the certs in the truststore are normally expected to be CA certs (and usually CA *root* certs, as the predefined ones are). Most client software obeys this instruction, though there are exceptions. Thus if your truststore contains certs like

```
Subject=Client1 Issuer=MyCA
Subject=Client2 Issuer=MyCA
Subject=Client3 Issuer=MyCA
```

then your server will ask for certs issued by any of `Client1 Client2 Client3` but *not* `MyCA`. If the client actually has only one cert and it is *for* e.g. `Client2` but is *issued by* `MyCA` -- not by any `Clientn` -- most client software will consider that cert unacceptable for this server/handshake.

**THE PKI WAY.** It is not true that a certificate can't be invalidated before expiration. PKI in general is explicitly designed to deal with such cases, which are generically termed **revocation**. There are various reasons a certificate can be revoked before expiring; for the particular PKI scheme used for SSL/TLS (and by Java for other things as well, like code signing), namely PKIX (or the effectively equivalent X.509) see [rfc5280 5.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-5.3.1) as well as the rest of section 5 for Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs), the older and traditional way of handling revocation, and [rfc6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) for Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP), the newer way.

For the 'real' (public) PKI this mostly just works. Java implements PKIX revocation checking, but for SSL/TLS (JSSE) it is **disabled by default**; you must set sysprop `com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation` to use it. You may also need to set `com.sun.security.enableCRLDP` for CRLs and AFAICT always need to set *security* property (not sysprop) `ocsp.enable` for OCSP. See e.g.:
[Check X509 certificate revocation status in Spring-Security before authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506661/check-x509-certificate-revocation-status-in-spring-security-before-authenticating)
[Checking a X509 Certificate Revocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637708/checking-a-x509-certificate-revocation)
[Java SSL Certificate Revocation Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301283/java-ssl-certificate-revocation-checking)

But running CRL distribution point(s) and/or OCSP responder(s) so that they are correct *and* available when needed -- which can be any time -- is non-trivial; this is one of the things real CAs charge money for (or get subsidized). Doing this for your own personal CA can vary from a pain in the butt to effectively impossible, but if you want to, be much more specific about your CA.

Your situation is in principle simpler; you have only one CA and you operate it, so you know when revocations occur. You could trivially provide the CRL(s) to the server when it(they) change. But AFAICS the builtin code has no way to *use* that information, so you'll have to use the hook that allows writing your own TrustManager in place of the builtin one, and modify it to use a validator with a CertStore that uses the CRLs. This is probably also a fair bit of work, but only once.

**WORKAROUNDS.** Instead of doing it 'right' in PKI terms, you could continue with your approach of trusting the leaf certs individually by modifying the server or the clients.

You could change the (X509)TrustManager hook in the server to validate certs as usual, but override `getAcceptedIssuers` to return a different (and correct for your case) list of 'requested' CAs, causing JSSE to send a CertificateRequest that causes the client(s) to use their correct cert(s).

Depending on the clients you might be able to change them to ignore the 'requested' CAs and send their cert anyway -- which the server's default TrustManager will validate if it is in the truststore (*or* the CA is). For OpenSSL this is easy; OpenSSL already ignores the requested CA list and just sends whatever is configured. For Java you could hook the client KeyManager and override `chooseClientAliases` method to not check against the list of desired issuers as it normally does. For other clients add to your Q or ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks dave, I understand that is not a easy way (without hooks) to use cert list directly in trustedStore without root ca.

Comment: I will read more about the new way with OCSP , seems good for me

Comment: I understand it's a workaround, but thanks to this answer I managed to trust the client certificate by proxying the KeyManager implementation and returning the specific client certificate in the chooseClientAliases method. In my case, I had lost the issuer cert and it was tricky to update the client certificate in the clients. So this was the fastest way for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

TrustStore.jks is how java will determine whether or not it trusts a certificate. Its essentially a keystore file of root certificates. You will have to add your root certificate to this store if you want to avoid "not trustes messages."

In your scenario, since you used that root to issue 10 client certificates, removing the client_certificate.crt from your trust or key stores wont distrust it. Because, by design, java is looking at the TrustStore and finding the root certificate and thus trusting client_certificate.crt still. You are going to need a redesign of your CA.

When deploying any sort of PKI infrastructure, you will need to also set up CRL and/or OCSP servers. These are the two protocols used to revoke a certificate.

I also recommend you do not issue "end user certificates" directly from the root. Its best issue intermediate certificates off the root, and then use intermediate_certificate.crt to issue your actual server or client certs.
For a reason why, see here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128779/why-is-it-more-secure-to-use-intermediate-ca-certificates#128800

And here is a great and easy way to deploy your own CA using OpenSSL. It will show you how to set up the root, intermediate, and revocation servers. https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/

Comment: Although CRL and/or OCSP is the PKIX answer in general, **Java SSL/TLS** by default disables them; see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I will think about my CA strategy